# How to add up the result in $.each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i am trying to read width of each item in topmenu element and add the width of item and assign to avariable. but when i run this code i am getting NaN in alert
what is the problem in this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.topmenu').each(function(menu){
        var btext = $(this).find('.baritem').width();
        alert(btext);
        var itemswidth = +itemswidth+btext;
        alert(itemswidth);
        //var width = getTextWidth(btext,"arial","40");
        //alert(width);     
    });
});
```

Comment: can u show the html code

Comment: `undefined + number == NaN`??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This line

```
var itemswidth = +itemswidth+btext;
```

adds `undefined` to a number. This gives `NaN`. You need to initialize `itemswidth` to `0` before entering the loop :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var itemswidth = 0;
  $('.topmenu').each(function(){
     var btext = $(this).find('.baritem').width();
     itemswidth += btext;
     console.log(itemswidth); // better than alert
  });
});
```

And for Florian :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var itemswidth = $('.topmenu .baritem').get().reduce(function(t,e){ 
        return t+$(e).width()
    }, 0);
    console.log(itemswidth);
});
```

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Happy now ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it easily with:

```
var reduce=Array.prototype.reduce;
var completeWidth=reduce.call($("div"), function(sum, elem){
    sum+=$(elem).width();
    return sum;
}, 0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DSUHG/

Comment: Mentioning browser compatibility would be a plus :-) And following the original example would be even better.